# how to change string key in dictionary inside list | python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, key

I want to change key name 'user_id' to 'sender' as example :

```
[{'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 1,
  'user_id': 1000000},
 {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 2,
  'user_id': 1000000},
 {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 3,
  'user_id': 1000000},
 {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 4,
  'user_id': 1000000}]
```

to :

```
[{'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 1,
  'sender': 1000000},
 {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 2,
  'sender': 1000000},
 {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 3,
  'sender': 1000000},
 {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 4,
  'sender': 1000000}]
```

what shoud I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just loop over the data and change the dicts appropriately assigning to the 
`'sender'` key what you [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) from `'user_id'`:

```
for d in data:
    d['sender'] = d.pop('user_id')
```

Comment: Wow... usually at least five people post list/dict comprehensions before someone posts a simple loop solution :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann True about the docs link, changed that. Even though little about `dict.pop` has changed from 2 to 3 :)

Answer (score 1):

**What about without loop ?**

One line Solution:

```
list(map(lambda x:x.__setitem__('sender',x.pop('user_id')),your_data))
```

data is:

```
your_data=[{'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 1,
  'user_id': 1000000},
 {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 2,
  'user_id': 1000000},
 {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 3,
  'user_id': 1000000},
 {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3',
  'message_id': 4,
  'user_id': 1000000}]
```

output:

```
[{'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3', 'message_id': 1, 'sender': 1000000}, {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3', 'message_id': 2, 'sender': 1000000}, {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3', 'message_id': 3, 'sender': 1000000}, {'chat_id': 'e3c2b14ded7a32c41bf0186b6172d8e3', 'message_id': 4, 'sender': 1000000}]
```